# Application of former versions

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, software-center, evolution

When I upgrade my version from 12.04 to 20.4:
Can I use the applications like Evolution and Libre Office Base, flashplayer, kaffein and other in the modern version. I have seen, that this applications are not provided in the software center.

Thanks for answers.

Kay

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 used a very different software stack to the versions used in later releases. I'm still using `evolution` (the mail MUA or mail user agent) program with the same mail data-base I used in versions before 12.04; but it's been progressively updated via various upgrades; not a huge jump of 8 years like you're talking about. Libreoffice likewise reads my files, but I can't speak to your actual databases. Some programs have changed, eg. Qt4 is now EOL being replaced by Qt5 so programs that used it may have changed (eg.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kaffeine)

Comment: Some older applications are available via *snap* or like containerized environments (flatpak etc), however you'd have to look yourself (that allows the libraries used by older software, eg. 12.04 may have some GTK2, Qt4 which is now EOL, but can be snapped or placed into containized packages allowing hem to be used in later releases)

Comment: Exactly what leads to to believe that these applications are not available in Ubuntu 20.04? I'm using two of them right now. Perhaps there is an underlying problem with the method of searching that we can help correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Software Center may show only Snaps.

The most authoritative information resource about deb-package is https://packages.ubuntu.com .

Applications from your list exist in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with versions:

- Evolution @ [3.36.1-2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/evolution)
- LibreOffice @ [6.4.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libreoffice-base)
- Kaffeine @ [2.0.18](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kaffeine)
- and so on.